# React redux submit and use data form submited in the next page

Tags: javascript, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form and on submit I am trying to pass submited data into another page where I should use submited redux-form data to build something else.
I am quite new into redux field but I am trying to understand how reducers and action creator works. At this point I am getting the submited data into action and in the reducer the payload is undefined. So how can I have the correct flow of submit form -> dispatch an action -> pass the data into reducer -> get the data into the next page.

this is my redux-form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/" autoComplete="off" noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitData)}>
  {initialFields.map((key, index) => {
      return (
          <Field key={index} label={key} name={key} component={renderTextField} />
      );
  })}
     <Button type="submit" disabled={submitting} size="small" variant="contained" color="primary"> Submit </Button> {/* onClick={submitting ? submitting : reset } */}
    <Button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} size="small" onClick={reset} variant="contained" color="secondary"> Clear Values </Button>
</form>
```

the export:

```
function mapStateToProps({ form }) {
  return form;
}

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({
      form: "swimForm",
      validate,
      asyncValidate,
    })(SwimForm));
```

action:

```
export const getSwimFormValues = (props) => async dispatch => {
  console.log("From Action",props)
  dispatch({
    type: SUBMIT_SWIM_FORM,
    payload: props.values
  });
};
```

and reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    values: []
  };

  export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case SUBMIT_SWIM_FORM:
          console.log("From Reducer", action,)
        return { 
          ...state, 
          values: payload
        };


      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does you entire page refresh, like when pressing F5 ? If this is the case, this is normal to lose the state of the store.
Try using XmlHttpRequest (like axios) so that the entire page does not refresh

Comment: @DavidAlvarez the page is not refreshing, just moving to another component (page) with   history.push('/NextPageComnponent') on valid submit

Comment: Maybe `action.payload` instead of `payload` ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all in action make sure to change `payload` to `action.payload` otherwsie it will always be undefined.
Then the part where you map state to props create an object like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // make sure that the name of the property with form values is actually `form`
  // you can log the state and see what exactly you need to assign
  console.log(state);
  return {
    form: state.form,
  }
};
```